# Login to Facebook

Tags: xcode, facebook, authentication

I am trying to popup the login page for Facebook with the code below. The sample code APIkey and secret key belongs to the sample code which works. However, then i change my own registered APIkey and secret key, the login page never popup.

May I know if i need to do anything on the facebook side?

```
static NSString* kApiKey = @"8fa673a06891cac667e55d690e27ecbb";
static NSString* kApiSecret = @"325a4c580253c7619313baad5712cc2a";
_session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:kApiKey secret:kApiSecret delegate:self] retain];

// Load a previous session from disk if available.  Note this will call session:didLogin if a valid session exists.
[_session resume];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the Facebook url handler in your info.plist file?  In the sample project, you would need to change it to fb152465604814562, or whatever your public app id is (not the private/public key).